# Inserting dates in database (the browser database) using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, sql, database

I've been working on a college project for which I need to use dates and enter them in the database (the built-in one in the Chrome browser). To be specific, I'll be taking a date from the user and enter it in the database.

The HTML code goes like this:

```
<html>
<head>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <input type="date" id="dt">
  <input type="button" id="submit" value="INSERT DATE">
</body>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/index.js"></script>
</html>
```

And the JavaScript:

```
var db = openDatabase("Dates", "1.0", "Test Dates", 200000);
var createStatement = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Date (sampledate DATE)";
var insertStatement = "INSERT INTO Date (sampledate) VALUES (?)";

db.transaction(function(tx) {
  tx.executeSql(createStatement, []);
});

$(document).ready(function() {
  $("body").fadeIn(2000);
  $("#submit").click(insertdate);
});

function insertdate() {
  var datetemp = $("#dt");
  db.transaction(function(tx) {
    tx.executeSql(insertStatement, [datetemp])
  })
  alert("SUCCESS");
}
```

This is what I get in the database:

[image: database screenshot]

So it'd be really great if I get some help!

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. What is your question? What is the expected result?

Comment: Should be aware that WebSql is a deprecated API. Might want to migrate to indexedDB

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are passing $("#dt") to the database, which is an jQuery encapsulated object that contains your input DOM object.

Just change this line:

```
var datetemp = $("#dt");
```

To this:

```
var datetemp = $("#dt").val();
```

It should work fine!

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

You are passing `[datetemp]` as an object.

```
function insertdate()
{
    var datetemp = $("#dt");
    db.transaction(function(tx)
                  {
        tx.executeSql(insertStatement, [datetemp])    // your passing the object here
        })
    alert("SUCCESS");
}
```

You need to iterate through this object and get the values. Write them to an array.

```
[datetemp].forEach(function(value){    // iterating through it . . .
    // do stuff here . . . (i.e inert values in to array)
});
```

Then add database

```
var insertStatement = "INSERT INTO Date [dbo].[sampledate] (col0, col1, col2 
// ect . . .) VALUES ([array].day, [array].month, [array].year // ect . . .)";

function insertdate()
{
    var datetemp = $("#dt");
    db.transaction(function(tx)
                  {
        tx.executeSql(insertStatement)    // just take the object out
        })
    alert("SUCCESS");
}
```

**OR**

Change the insert command and put that after you have the `[datetime]` this would be simplier :)

```
var insertStatement = "INSERT INTO Date [dbo].[sampledate] (col0, col1, col2 
// ect . . .) VALUES ([datetemp].day, [datetemp].month, [datetemp].year  // 
ect . . .))";

function insertdate()
{
    var datetemp = $("#dt");
    db.transaction(function(tx)
                  {
        tx.executeSql(insertStatement)    // just take the object out
        })
    alert("SUCCESS");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are passing the datetime object instead of text box value
use Val function in Jquery
 var datetemp = $("#dt").val();